# AlarmManager Call Method Within Class

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I would like to use an AlarmManager to call a specific method within a class that is ALREADY being called periodically by another AlarmManager. Effectively, I would like to use an AlarmManager rather than a Timer, because a Timer's delay is ignored when the Phone is not in active use. So, now instead of having a timer do something like this...

```
Timer theTimer = new Timer();
    theTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(checkIfGooglePlay()) {
                getPostLocation();
                stopSelf();

                mLocationClient.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }, TWO_MINUTES);
```

I would like an AlarmManager to do something very similarly. However it appears like I have to call ANOTHER class periodically instead of simply letting me set a Timer-like function within the same class. It is important to do it within the same class, in my case, because I am giving a LocationClient two minutes to connect.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need to give the LocationClient two minutes to connect. Normally it shouldn't take that long. In addition, calling LocationClient.connect() is synchronous, so it comes back immediately. If the connection fails because of some problem, the method onConnectionFailed() is called. There should be no need to wait.

It might help if you explained what you're trying to do with location detection. We might be able to give you a different strategy to pursue. Sometimes when you change your approach, everything becomes much more simple.

Comment: Hi @Joe, I believe I have clarified my question in this new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429961/service-calling-alarmmanager-on-another-service. Thanks!